# jQuery Cross domain asmx web service call return results but still jQuery shows it as an error

Tags: jquery, asp.net, cross-domain, asmx

I am calling through jQuery an AJAX enabled asmx web service hosted in a remote ASP.Net website.

The jQuery is on a page hosted on my localhost ASP.Net website.

The problem is that jQuery is showing an error (i.e. error callback is triggered) when the above call is made, even though when I inspect the response in Fiddler, there is no error, but the correct expected value from the web service. The correct return value is 'true' which is being returned as seen in Fiddler. **I cannot figure out what I am missing in my cross-domain call.**

**jQuery code** to call Cross Domain asmx service

```
     var userName = 'mike';
     var password = 'abcd';
    var serviceurl = "http://www.kandoodev.com/WebService1.asmx/LoginUser";
                    $.ajax({
                        url: serviceurl,
                        type: 'GET',
                        crossDomain: true,
                        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                        data:{ userName: userName, password:   password  },
                        dataType: "jsonp",
                        success: function (msg) {
                            alert('Cross-Domain Web service call succeeded. We will now call a protected method on the web service. ' + JSON.stringify(msg));
                                   if (msg.toString() === 'true') {
                                       alert('Valid Credentials');   
                                }
                                else {
                                    alert('Invalid Credentials');   
                            }
                        },
                        error: function (error) { alert('ERROR has occurred!'); alert(JSON.stringify(error)) }
                    });
```

**WebService1.asmx**

```
    [WebService(Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/")]
    [WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
    [System.ComponentModel.ToolboxItem(false)]
    // To allow this Web Service to be called from script, using ASP.NET AJAX, uncomment the 
    //following line. 
[System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]

public class WebService1 : System.Web.Services.WebService 
{
 [WebMethod]
 [PrincipalPermission(SecurityAction.Assert, Unrestricted = true)]
 [ScriptMethod(UseHttpGet = true, ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
    public bool LoginUser(string userName, string password)
     {
        bool authenticated = false;

        if (userName.ToLower() == "mike" && password.ToLower() == "abcd")//you can instead check credentials against a users table in database 
        {
            authenticated = true;
        }
        return authenticated;
     }
}
```

The values in error callback are as below:
[image: Error Callback Parameter Values]

**The TextView in Fiddler of Response is as below.**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<boolean xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">true</boolean>
```

Comment: does the error callback trigger and what error do you get ?

Comment: Yes the error callback triggers, but there doesn't seem to be an error. Error parameter values are -  readyState:4, status:200 and statusText:success.

Comment: are you calling a http remote from a https page ?

Comment: Not https. Calling http remote from http: //localhost:50676/WebForm1.aspx. So the jQuery call is on Webform1.aspx on my local machine.

Comment: You're returning xml to an ajax-call who expect to receive  dataType: "jsonp" ?

Comment: But I have ResponseFormat.Json for the web service method I am calling. Still why is it returning xml?

Comment: I don't have the knowledge to help you with your server configuration. But if it's returning xml to the jsonp-call, then I would start with solving that issue.

Answer (score 0):

Did you check whether the Preflight request (i.e Option request) to the webserver is returning headers Access-Control-Allow-Origin:* (or the allowed domain name) and Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST (or any other verbs) in the response.Because there are cases where preflight request returns 200 OK but miss the CORS headers.